# iOS rubymotion app poor performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, rubymotion

My app works smooth on emulator, but is extremely slow and laggy on real device(iPhone 4). Push animation is laggy and scrolling is now smooth. 
Here is an example of view controller https://gist.github.com/Dark-Sun/37daeb4cf05c58d4f421

Answer (score 0):

hummmm. Maybe u can try this tool.http://oneapm.io/en.html.
It is not a simulator but a monitoing tool which can help u monitor the process of app in real device.